# Test if implicit exists

Tags: scala, macros

Is it possible on compile time using macros to test if exists some implicit for current type ?

something like this

```
def packOne(tpe:c.universe.Type,....) = {
  if(tpe =:= ByteTpe ) makeast1
  else if (tpe =:= LongTpe ) makeast2
  else if (tpe =:= c.typeOf[java.lang.String]) makeast3
  ....
  else exists implicit convention for TPE { 
  q"""
  // call some function with implicit PACK[T]
   implicitly[Packer[$tpe]].pack(...)
  """
  } else {
  // Make default conversion
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to use `inferImplicitValue`:

```scala
val t = c.internal.typeRef(NoPrefix, typeOf[Packer[_]].typeSymbol, List(tpe))
c.inferImplicitValue(t) match {
  case EmptyTree => … // default conversion
  case packer => q"packer.pack(…)"
}
```

Comment: strange but it does not work in test env : 
this macro does not find Implicit 
https://github.com/martende/mondao/blob/master/src/main/scala/mondao/Macro.scala#L110
 in test 
https://github.com/martende/mondao/blob/master/src/test/scala/MacroSpec.scala#L48

Comment: Did you change the source in the meantime? I just cloned your repo but get an error for `BsonNumber($nameStr)` (not applicable to string). AFAICS there is no usage of `inferImplicitValue`.

Comment: This was a first try to use inferImplicitValue https://github.com/martende/mondao/blob/9a7e0f05b0cfdc43e97e1bae4b8194743eda2d59/src/main/scala/mondao/Macro.scala#L112

Comment: Yeah, not sure why my example seemed to work in my sandbox. It is probably necessary to construct the type reference manually. I updated the answer accordingly. In your source code it would be `c.internal.typeRef(NoPrefix, typeOf[Writes[_]].typeSymbol, List(tpe))`.

Comment: First line can be simplified to `val t = c.universe.appliedType(typeOf[Packer[_]], tpe)`